# Does anyone run a service to POST data from client-side application?

Tags: javascript, post, saas

I have a static JavaScript-only data visualisation. I want to collect the user's name and email before showing them the visualisation.

I have written a popup form to collect this info. But where can I store it? Do I have to add a whole back-end service and database just to store two variables?

I just need to POST two text strings, safely and reliably, from client-side JavaScript, and download the data as needed. Surely someone must offer a service that allows this? I would happily pay to avoid writing my own backend.

(I've looked at embedding a Mailchimp form, but it's too painful to style it in the way I need - I'd prefer to use my own front-end code.)

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/

Comment: You can post to Google Forms for free. I wrote a simple how-to guide here: http://douglasduhaime.com/posts/crud-operations-on-static-file-sites.html

Comment: what's your current backend environment?

Comment: If you are using Mailchimp already use a back end sdk to proxy request from front end. If not can set up firebase mentioned above  in minutes

Comment: @JaromandaX nginx serving static pages.

Comment: Thanks, but is Firebase going to work in web client-side code? It looks like it requires authentication. [EDIT] Found https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#add_firebase_to_your_app - is it safe to include these config details in client-side code?

Comment: In addition - I'm required to host on a non-HTTPS domain. Don't think Firebase will work on an HTTP site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at Campaign monitor ?

You can create a `List` that has the name + email then you can push this data to that list using AJAX:

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/appstore/ajax-subscription-form/

Comment: Thanks - that's what I ended up doing!

Answer (score 0):

[AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/) Mobile Hub (DynamoDB, Lambda, API Gateway, Cognito)

-Integrated console that helps you create, build, test, and monitor your mobile apps that leverage AWS services

[Parse server](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server)

-Open source server released by Parse/Facebook to replicate functionality of Parse

[remoteStorage](https://remotestorage.io/)

-Everything in one place – your place. Use a storage account with a provider you trust, or set up your own storage server. Move house whenever you want. It's your data.